# Textbox Search Gridview with stored procedure ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have Stored Procedure sp_ItemFilter, but the problem is when I insert a data in the textbox, I press btnButton to send the data, not shown in the gridview becomes empty, how I can fix this?
Code used.

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Cmd = New SqlCommand("sp_codefilter", Cnn)
    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    With Cmd.Parameters
        .Add("@codigo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 6).Value = TextBox1.Text
        Cnn.Open()
        Try
            Dim dv As New DataView
            Da = New SqlDataAdapter(Cmd)
            Ds = New DataSet
            GridView1.DataSource = Ds.Tables()
            GridView1.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            Cnn.Close()
        End Try
    End With
End Sub
End Class
```

thanks for reading my post

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Da = New SqlDataAdapter(Cmd)
Ds = New DataSet   //<---- this DataSet is empty and needs filling

Da.Fill(Ds);  //<------- You need to fill the DataSet here

GridView1.DataSource = Ds.Tables(0)
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill the data set, set the select command, and bind a specific table to the GridView:

```
Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand("sp_codefilter", Cnn)
Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
With Cmd.Parameters
    .Add("@codigo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 6).Value = TextBox1.Text
End With

Cnn.Open()
Try
    Dim dv As New DataView
    Da = New SqlDataAdapter()
    Ds = New DataSet
    Da.SelectCommand = Cmd
    Da.Fill(ds, "MyTable");
    GridView1.DataSource = Ds.Tables("MyTable")
    GridView1.DataBind()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    Cnn.Close()
End Try
```